Playwright playing back responses in round-robin approach
The scenario is such that an app makes a sequence of API calls, where the same endpoint is called multiple times, but the response is different each time.  For instance:

App calls endpoint "/load-transaction" --> loads the current version of a "transaction.
App calls endpoint "/update-transaction" --> updates the transaction with some user-specified data.
App calls endpoint "/load-transaction" --> loads the current version of a "transaction.  This response would have a different response from the first instance.

We have used Playwright's HAR file recording and playback; but we have not been able to figure out a solution to the round-robin response implementation.

Please provide a sample app and test cases as a [mcve]. It's hard to write an answer from nothing and expect it to work for whatever your specific use case is. Thanks.
